# How do I add spacing between two cells in UITableView? There's nothing like separator height or something

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I need a layout something like in attached image. I have tried adding a subView at the bottom of UICell but it actually distorts the other items UI. Can someone please help? I am working in Xamarin.iOS

[image]

Comment: The recommended approach to this that I usually see are spacer views at the bottom of each UITableViewCell. If that approach "stretches" your UI, it sounds like some constraints are wrong, or you're using an incorrect fixed height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use sections and section footers:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 5
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    // your spacing
    return 20
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let footer = UIView()
    footer.backgroundColor = .clear
    footer.isOpaque = false
    return footer
}
```

Comment: Thanks It Worked for me :)

Answer (score 2):

One option is to design the cell as the xib.

[image: view image attached]

Comment: This is definitely the easiest way if you're using .xibs

Comment: Thank you Very Much :) THis is a Good Idea, But actually I am not using .xibs.

Comment: You can create the same effect in code as well. Add as a subview to contentView with leading,trailing,top and bottom constraint creating a padding. In image provided consider the grey area in the ContentView